# How to remove special character when writing to docx?

Tags: python, pymongo, docx

I'm looking for some advice on removing special characters.
To explain what's going on. I'm writing a mongo-query to a docx but having some trouble removing special characters when writing to the word document. I'm new to python but any advice on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

```
document = Document()

special_char='_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:;[]'

document.add_heading('This is a document',0)
for i in queryOutput: #imported Mongo Query 
    for y in special_char:
        p=document.add_paragraph(str(i).replace(y,"")) 
       
    
document.save('output.docx')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

for paragraph in queryOutput:
    sanitized_paragraph = re.sub("|".join(special_char), "", paragraph)
    p = document.add_paragraph(sanitized_paragraph)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex pattern to replace multiple special characters. Piotr's answer gives some basic ideas, but he did not mention that some special characters have special meanings. So they should be escaped before using as follows:

```
import re
document = Document()

special_characters = "_!#$%^&*\(\)<>?\/\\\\|\}\{~:;\[\]"
pattern = "[" + special_characters + "]"
document.add_heading('This is a document',0)
for i in queryOutput: #imported Mongo Query 
    cleaned_p = re.sub(pattern, "", str(i))
    p=document.add_paragraph(cleaned_p)         
document.save('output.docx')
```